# Killing service through batch or something similar

Tags: batch-file, service, windows-8, wia

The WIA service(stisvc) on my friend's win8 computer quite often stops working properly. When stopping/restarting from MMC it returns error "Service didn't respond in time", so I kill it from the Task Manager and then start it from within MMC.
Is there a way to make a script to *kill* the stisvc and then start it again?

Answer (score 0):

**This works for you (You should have Admin rights on your system):**

```
@echo off

taskkill /F /IM svchost.exe /FI "SERVICES eq stisvc"

sc query stisvc | find /i "running"
if errorlevel 1 (
echo Not running...
echo Starting Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) service....
net start stisvc
)
```

**Dependencies:**

Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) will not start, if the following services are stopped or disabled:

```
Remote Procedure Call (RPC)
Shell Hardware Detection
```